# How to merge rows with the same values in each column of the table?

Tags: html, arrays, merge, row, codeigniter-3

In this code, I'm using CI 3. I want to merge the rows vertically when there are the same values in each column of the table. The columns I want to merge if there are the same values in their rows are: supplier_name, crf_no, crf_date, crf_vs_psi_status, sop_no, sop_date, psi_no, psi_date, po_no, po_date, pi_no, pi_date, and pi_vs_psi_status

Here is the code:

```
TrackingReportModel.php
    public function getSupplierTrackingReport($searchBy, $supId, $dateFrom, $dateTo)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT s.supplier_name, cus.l_acroname, c.crf_no, c.crf_date, c.status AS crf_vs_psi_status, sop.sop_no, sop.date_created AS sop_date, pro.proforma_code AS psi_no, pro.delivery_date AS psi_date, po.po_no, po.order_date AS po_date, pi.pi_no, pi.posting_date AS pi_date, pi.status AS pi_vs_psi_status
            FROM proforma_header pro
            INNER JOIN customers cus ON cus.customer_code = pro.customer_code
            INNER JOIN crf c ON c.crf_id = pro.crf_id
            INNER JOIN po_header po ON po.po_header_id = pro.po_header_id
            INNER JOIN sop_head sop ON sop.sop_id = c.sop_id
            INNER JOIN purchase_invoice_header pi ON pi.po_header_id = po.po_header_id
            LEFT JOIN suppliers s ON s.supplier_id = pro.supplier_id
            WHERE c.crf_date >= ? AND c.crf_date <= ?";

        if ($searchBy == 'All Supplier') {
            $params = array($dateFrom, $dateTo);
        } else if ($searchBy == 'Supplier') {
            $sql .= " AND pro.supplier_id = ?";
            $params = array($dateFrom, $dateTo, $supId);
        }

        $sql .= " ORDER BY s.supplier_name, pro.proforma_code, po.po_no, pi.posting_date ASC";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

```
TrackingReportControllerCode.php
    private function printReport($data, $from, $to)
    {
        $dateFrom = date("M d, Y", strtotime($from));
        $dateTo   = date("M d, Y", strtotime($to));

        $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
        // set document information
        $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
        $pdf->SetAuthor('Mariel Taray');
        $pdf->SetTitle('Tracking Report');
        $pdf->SetSubject('CWO Transaction Tracking Report');
        $pdf->SetKeywords('CWO, Transaction, Tracking, Report');
        // set default header data
        $pdf->SetHeaderData('alturas.png', 32, '' . '', 'Cash With Order Monitoring Report');
        // set header and footer fonts
        $pdf->setHeaderFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
        $pdf->setFooterFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
        // set default monospaced font
        $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
        // set margins
        $pdf->SetMargins(15, 20, 15);
        $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
        $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
        // set auto page breaks
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
        // set image scale factor
        $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
        $pdf->AddPage('L', array(215.9, 355.6));
        $pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);

        $html = '<div style=" text-align: left;">
                        <span style="font-size: xx-large;padding-left:20px;"><b>CWO TRANSACTION - TRACKING REPORT</b></span><br>
                        <span style="font-size: medium;padding-left:20px">Report Date: ' . date('F d, Y') . '</span><br>
                        <span style="font-size: medium;padding-left:20px">From : ' . $dateFrom . ' To : ' . $dateTo . '</span><br>            
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span style="font-size: medium;padding-left:20px;">The provided table represents the CWO transactions, including supplier information, CRF/CV number and CRF date, CRF vs PSI status, SOP number and SOP date, PSI number, PSI date, PO number and PO date, PI number and PI date, and PI vs PSI status.</span><br>
                    </div>

                         <table border="1" >
                     <thead>
                         <tr>
                            <th colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#1d2120" color="white" style="border: 1px solid #c96a16">SUPPLIER</th>
                            <th align="center" bgcolor="#1d2120" color="white" style="border: 1px solid #c96a16">CRF/CV NO.</th>
                            <th align="center" bgcolor="#1d2120" color="white" style="border: 1px solid #c96a16">CRF DATE</th>
                            <th align="center" bgcolor="#1d2120" color="#ccffff" style="border: 1px solid #c96a16">CRF VS PSI STATUS</th>
                            <th align="center" bgcolor="#1d2120" color="white" style="border: 1px solid #c96a16">SOP NO.</th>
                            <th align="center" bgcolor="#1d2120" color="white" style="border: 1px solid #c96a16">SOP DATE</th>
                            <th align="center" bgcolor="#1d2120" color="white" style="border: 1px solid #c96a16"> PSI NO.</th>
                            <th align="center" bgcolor="#1d2120" color="white" style="border: 1px solid #c96a16"> PSI DATE</th>
                            <th align="center" bgcolor="#1d2120" color="white" style="border: 1px solid #c96a16"> PO NO.</th>
                            <th align="center" bgcolor="#1d2120" color="white" style="border: 1px solid #c96a16"> PO DATE</th>
                            <th align="center" bgcolor="#1d2120" color="white" style="border: 1px solid #c96a16"> PI NO.</th>
                            <th align="center" bgcolor="#1d2120" color="white" style="border: 1px solid #c96a16"> PI DATE</th>
                            <th align="center" bgcolor="#1d2120" color="#ffff99" style="border: 1px solid #c96a16"> PI VS PSI STATUS</th>
                         </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';

        foreach ($data as $b) {

            $html .= '<tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">' . $b['supplier_name'] . '</td>
                <td align="center">' . $b['crf_no'] . '</td>
                <td align="center">' . (empty($b['crf_date']) ? '' : date("m-d-Y", strtotime($b['crf_date']))) . '</td>
                <td align="center" style="color: ' . ($b['crf_vs_psi_status'] === 'PENDING' ? 'red' : 'green') . ';">' . $b['crf_vs_psi_status'] . '</td>
                <td align="center">' . $b['sop_no'] . '</td>
                <td align="center">' . (empty($b['sop_date']) ? '' : date("m-d-Y", strtotime($b['sop_date']))) . '</td>
                <td align="center">' . $b['psi_no'] . '</td>
                <td align="center">' . (empty($b['psi_date']) ? '' : date("m-d-Y", strtotime($b['psi_date']))) . '</td>
                <td align="center">' . $b['po_no'] . '</td>
                <td align="center">' . (empty($b['po_date']) ? '' : date("m-d-Y", strtotime($b['po_date']))) . '</td>
                <td align="center">' . $b['pi_no'] . '</td>  
                <td align="center">' . (empty($b['pi_date']) ? '' : date("m-d-Y", strtotime($b['pi_date']))) . '</td>
                <td align="center" style="color: ' . ($b['pi_vs_psi_status'] === 'PENDING' ? 'red' : 'green') . ';">' . $b['pi_vs_psi_status'] . '</td>
            </tr>';
        }

        $html .= '</tbody></table>';
        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
        $fileName = 'TRANSACTION_TRACKING_REPORT_' . time() . '.pdf';
        $pdf->Output(getcwd() . '/files/Reports/TrackingReports/' . $fileName, 'F');
        return $fileName;
    }
```

Here is the generated html table converted to pdf file:
[Pdf table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hm1v.png)

I want it to fix the code to remove duplicates values